# Non vanishing smooth vector field on the solid $g-$torus that points inwards

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, manifolds-with-boundary

If I think to the surface genus $g$-torus as the boundary of a solid genus $g$-torus in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, is it possible to have a nonvanishing smooth vector field such that in every point is pointing inward ?

I think the answer is no if $g \ne 1$ : this should follows from the fact that for the Hopf-Lemma given such field than the sum of the index, i.e. $0$ for the sake of contradiction should be equal the gauss map on the boundary, which means the genus $g$-torus, which is $1-g$ for a known fact.

So $g=1$ is the only problem to deal with, and I think that even for $g = 1$ the statement can't hold but I couldn't find any contradiction in that,

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I thought : doesn't the Hopf's Lemma say that if $M$ is an oriented compact $n$-manifold in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with boundary given an outward vector field of the boundary, i.e $X \in T_p M - C_pM$ then the sum of index of the vector field equals the degree of the gauss map ? Where $X$ is the vector field and $p \in \partial M$

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread your question - you want a vector field on the solid torus, not the torus? What does “inward” mean then?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Outward to me means by definition that, taken $p \in \partial M$, $X(p) \in T_p M - C_pM$ where $C_p M$ is the tangent cone. So a vector is inward if $-v$ is outward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a vector field exists: The solid torus is the surface of revolution of the closed disc, so it can be described with three coordinates $(r,\theta,\varphi)\in[0,1]\times[0,2\pi)^2$, e.g. with the embedding
$$
\begin{pmatrix}r\\\theta\\\varphi\end{pmatrix}\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}(2+r\cos\varphi)\cos\theta\\(2+r\cos\varphi)\sin\theta\\r\sin\varphi\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^3
$$
Using $\partial_r,\partial_\theta,\partial_\varphi$ as the corresponding tangent frame, I claim the vector field $V=\partial_\theta-r\partial_r$ is a smooth nonvanishing vector field that is inward pointing on the boundary. One can check smoothness easily enough by writing $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Thanks Kajelad, could you please give me an idea of what this vector fields looks like on the torus ? But most importantly how did you thought about it, thanks.

Comment: Thinking of the solid torus as a "doughnut" in $\mathbb{R}^3$, one can start with a rotationally symmetric inward pointing vector field which vanishes on the central circle (this is the $-r\partial_r$ part). Then, to remove the zero, you can add a vector field which is parallel to the central circle (this is the $\partial_\theta$ part). Since the $-r\partial_r$ part is symmetric w.r.t. rotations, it will be everywhere perpendicular to $\partial_\theta$.

Comment: Another way of thinking about it is that the solid torus admits a nonvanishing vector field which is everywhere parallel to the boundary ($\partial_\theta$, the generator of the rotational symmetry). Such a field can always be slightly deformed to be everywhere inward-pointing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm going to try to visualize your thoughts.

Comment: Doesn't the vector field vanishes at $\theta = \varphi = \frac{\pi}{4}$ and $r = 1 $ ?